# Flask SocketIO is executing single request at a time

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

My simple flask socketIO app, but at a time only single request is executing the method "write_message".
I am using eventlet (https://eventlet.net/), which as per documentation can handle concurrent requests.

```
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('write-message', namespace='/message') 
def write_message(data):
    //long task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting socket app on port 5000")
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: I have added 'socketio = SocketIO(app,  async_mode="eventlet")'.    Does eventlet has number of max number of requests configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use gunicorn gevent to serve socket application . as per documentation.

"gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 module:app"


https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do in that long task is actually key here. Eventlet is a cooperative multitasking framework, so you need each task to release the CPU to allow other tasks to run. If your long task does not release the CPU, then no other tasks will be able to run at the same time.

A common way to release CPU in a long task with eventlet is to call `socketio.sleep(0)` often. Add this inside your loop if that is what you have in your long task.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am running Deep learning model, it can take few seconds.